# How to check email local-part before"@" not exceeding 64 characters in android?

Tags: android

I had implemented edit text where user can type his/her email Id to check email Id is correct or not I had made some validation which is working fine but problem is that when I write local-part,for example "user@gmail.com" here "user was local-part I want to check whether local-part is not exceeding 64 character.How can I do that pls help.

Note:- I want to only check local-part not exceeding 64 characters.

```
/*validation for email*/
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {// validation for email Id
    boolean isValid = false;
    String expression = "^([_A-Za-z0-9-\\+])+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,255})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;

    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this article. It's about checking a string length with regEx: https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/using-regular-expressions-to-check-string-length/

Comment: Just accept any e-mail presented to you and try to send an e-mail to it. You get a human response? It's a valid e-mail address. You get no response? Well, it means nothing.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(email.split("@")[0].length > 64) {
   // length greater than 64
}
else {
   // length less than or equal to 64
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```
String string = "user@gmail.com";
String[] parts = string.split("@");
String part1 = parts[0]; // user
String part2 = parts[1]; // gmail.com

if(part1.length()>64) 

    return true;

else 

   return false;
```

Comment: and how to check parts[0] is more than or less than 64 characters

Comment: if(part1.length()>64) return false;   Edit: length() not length

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String expression= "userMailId@gmail.com";
String[] value= expression.split("@");
String beforeat=value[0];//userMailId
String afterat=value[1];//gmail.com
```